# How to get Flask+Swagger ask for options for the parameters in the UI instead of filling a json?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flask-restx

I am using Python, Flask, flask_restx (Resource, Namespace, fields).
I want the user to see something like below where he can fill the required fields
[snip 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7BKy.png)

instead of writing up the whole json like below
[snip 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFbLD.png)

I tried using the params paramter in the decorator for my get method like below , but it started throwing `Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."`

```
@prompts_namespace.route('/')
class Prompt(Resource):
    @prompts_namespace.doc(params={'id': 'Id of prompt to retrieve'})
    def get(self): #kz no body
        """
        get a prompt with provided id

        Returns

        Prompt from CosmosDB
        -------

        """
        body = request.json
        prompt_id = body.get('prompt_id')
        filters = {"id": prompt_id}
        result = prompt_service.get_prompt(filters)
        print(result)

        return jsonify(result)
```

I guess this is something related to headers vs body but I am unable to google search with the correct words in order to understand this. Also I am not able to understand what Swagger  UI means by "payload" and what it means by "query" (in my snippings above)

Already mentioned what I tried.